# How to remove png transparency from iframe coming in my wordpress site

Tags: css, image, wordpress, iframe, transparency

White background is rounding my iframe, as i am echoing this iframe from the database although its showing correctly in all other browser except IE8, IE9(plz check the screenshot). Although i tried this script in my header.php as site is on `wordpress` but still no luck( included ie6pngfix.js under js folder). Let me know how can i fix that.

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ie6pngfix.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
DD_belatedPNG.fix('img, ul, ol, li, div, p, a, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, png, span');
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Details are as follows --

```
<div id="banner_right">
<iframe width="483" height="300" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/EDPYq4BFHBI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>       
</div>

#banner_right iframe{background:url(images/bg.png) 0 0 no-repeat;padding: 20px 13px 27px;}
```

`bg.png` is of `510X351` px

CORRECT SCREENSHOT, in all except IE8-9 -- (without-white-background)
[image]

INCORRECT SCREENSHOT,  IE8-9 -- (with-white-background)
[image]

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found answer on my own --

Add `allowtransparency="true"` to iframe code.

```
<iframe width="483" height="300" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/EDPYq4BFHBI" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Then add `background-color:transparent;` to my css--

```
#banner_right iframe{background:url(images/bg.png) 0 0 no-repeat;padding: 20px 13px 27px; background-color:transparent; }
```

Comment: You can condense that rule and include `background-color` in the background shorthand notation: `background: transparent url(images/bg.png) 0 0 no-repeat;`

Comment: @steveax thx a lot bro for the info ..little weak with css ..really struggle sometimes :(